# Tracing vfs_write(), how can I tell when writing to STDIN?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm tracing [`vfs_write()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=3.4#L420) using [KProbes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) on Kernel 3.4, and I want to be able to know when `write()` was called with `STDIN`.

At first, I thought I should learn how Standard Streams are implemented in Linux Kernel, so I went on and learned about the PTY/TTY filesystem.

Naively, I checked if the filesystem of the `struct file` that is being written to is `PTYFS`, but I discovered that none of the files that are being used by the task are of `PTYFS` type. So I went on and printed the filesystems that *are* being used by the task, and even wrote a special string to `STDIN`, so I could `grep` the logs on it later on.

I discovered that writes to `STDIN` are actually written to a `pipe`, using [`write_pipefifo_fops`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/pipe.c?v=3.4#L896). Surprisingly, this `pipe` is not referenced by `current->files->fdt->fd[0]`.

This is where I get lost. I want to understand the relationship between the `struct file` entry of `current->files->fdt->fd[0]` and the `struct file` entry that is passed as an argument to `vfs_write()` when a write to `STDIN` is executed.

Comment: "*Write was called with STDIN*". This is where I stumbled ... and I'm pretty sure that STDOUT is e.g. a real file when, redirecting to a file, a pipe when using IO redirection and something else otherwise. Why not trace the `write()` system call such that `write(STDOUT_FILENO, ...)`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly.My intentions are to trace execution of applications that takes their input through STDIN, during their runtime, like `bash`. I want to trace the `struct file` and not `STDIN_FILENO` since a simple call to `dup2(STDOUT_FILENO)` will make me miss everything that went through the new fd.

I didn't really understand why you suggest tracing `STDOUT`, I'm not after prints to the screen.

Comment: There can be multiple file objects that reference the underlying IO object (e.g. the fifo). For the pipe case, the one you are looking for is the write end of the pipe and that will not appear das `fd[0]`, because it is not the current process that is writing to the pipe.